# Excluding certain Regex Permutations

Tags: regex

Is there a way to exclude certain permutations in RegEx?

at present I am replacing all instances of:
[ouh]+

with:
[ouh]+

and it returns:

oo
ou
oh

uo
uu
uh

ho
hu
hh

I would like to exclude uo, uu, uh, ho, hu, and hh. How do I do this?

Comment: It is unclear, what your input is and what you're doing

Comment: For instance, "halo" should return "halo" "haloo" "halou" and "haloh" but not "haluo" "haluu" "haluh" "halho" "halhu" or "halhh"

Comment: By what replacement `halo` can return `halou`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your somewhat limited example, it appears you want to find all two-character strings composed only of the letters `o`, `u`, and `h`, where the first letter is not `u` or `h`. If that is the case, then perhaps `o[ouh]` would be a better regex to start with...

Comment: That worked! Just added a ? at the end, in conjunction with (o|ou|oh|oo)+ it gave me exactly what I wanted. Thank you!